# Image size considering (or not) h/v resolution

Tags: c#, image, resolution

I have two images:

```
Name   Type  Width  Height  HRes  VRes  
img01  GIF   256    256     384   96  
img02  TIFF  1728   1147    200   100
```

Windows internal viewer shows them using different *patterns*:

- **img01** is displayed as 256x256 image (square)
- **img02** is displayed as a vertical image (despite of width>height) and image format is correct

After seen **img02** behaviour I thought that displayed size is given by:

```
Display_Width  = max(HRes,VRes) * Width / HRes
Display_Height = max(HRes,VRes) * Height / VRes
```

But that's not good for **img01**, which is displayed as 256x256!!
If I use [Image class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) to load those images, resolution is not taken in account, so **img02** is shown horizontally and distorced respect correct format.
If Windows internal viewer shows them correctly, I think there should be some property to understand if resolution should be considered or not.
With [Image class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) I have [Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.flags.aspx) and [PropertyItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.flags.aspx) properties, but I really don't understand if they are the ones I have to look at.

Can you teach me the right method to display images (using Image class) without distortion?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aspect ratio in GIF files is very uncommon, since GIF is a format used to store graphics intended to be displayed on computer screens. In fact, GIF87a files do not have an aspect ratio at all, and GIF89a do not store the actual aspect ratio but an approximation.

On the other side, TIFF files for the most part are used by graphic designers, photographers and publishers, so the concept of pixel aspect ratio is core to the format as it allows these files to move between different display mediums.

My guess is that most GIF decoders ignore the aspect ratio from the GIF89a format. I think you should do the same.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, +1 for your answer because it sound reasonable. I'd like to have other answers to understand if there is a _always valid_ method before starting to discriminate by file type. I hope I can find some bit set or not inside Image properties...

Comment: Did you check the pixel aspect ratio field in your GIF image? All the images I checked have it set to 0, which means 1:1.

Comment: I was wondering about the GIF image, not your image class. Does it have a pixel aspect ratio? Where did you get the 384/96 HRes/VRes numbers from if not from aspect ratio?

Comment: From Image class: it has both Size and Resolution (horizontal and vertical). Same data is given by Explorer property tab...