# Image sizes in a FileInfo variable

Tags: c#, .net, variables, fileinfo

I'm currently working on a control which displays all images held within a folder so that the client is aware of what they have uploaded.

I have set attributes I wish to display, in order to keep them informed on what they have uploaded. So far everything is going well but I have come across a small problem.

What I would like to do is display the height and width of the uploaded images, but I currently can't find a way of doing this. Can anyone point me in the right direction??

So far my code looks like this:

```
FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(@"..\_includes\images\uploads\") + folder).GetFiles();

var imagefiles = from FileInfo f in files
                         where f.Exists
                         select new
                         {
                             url = imageurl + f.Name,
                             name = f.Name,
                             creation = f.CreationTime.ToLongDateString(),
                             filesize = (f.Length / 1024).ToString() + "KB",
                         };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load the image into an [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) object - this will give you the dimensions of the image.

```
using(var img = Image.FromFile(file.Name))
{
  var height = img.Height;
  var width = img.Width;
}
```

Comment: @Callum - I wouldn't do image operations within a LINQ query. You can loop over `imagefiles` and use the example code in the loop.

Comment: @AndersForsgren - Not fool proof. From the top of your linked article: "**Some** image files contain metadata". _Some_. Not all.

Comment: Put a *using* statement around this code, forgotten too often and particularly nasty in this case due to the file locking.

Answer (score 1):

You could try (but could be RAM and CPU consuming)

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(your_file);
```

and use `img.Width` and `img.Height`.

Note that those infos can be *wrong*: see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720206/image-size-considering-or-not-h-v-resolution).